# Absolute beginner not sure what is wrong with this code involving random.randint

Tags: python-3.x

Typing 'no' is giving me the first two responses randomly (according to what choice the computer makes), which is what I want. But, for some reason currently unseen to me whenever I type 'yes' I only get the first 'yes' response (line 15).

Here's the program:

```
import random
var1 = 'Bro'
var2 = 'high'
compHigh = random.randint(0, 1)
compHigh = 'no' if compHigh == 0 else compHigh == 'yes'
while True:
    answer = input('Hey %s, are you %s?: ' % (var1, var2))
    if answer == 'no' and answer != compHigh: 
        print('Okay %s, you are not %s, but I am!' % (var1, var2))
        break
    if answer == 'no' and answer == compHigh:
        print('Yo, %s. Neither of us are %s.' % (var1, var2))
        break
    if answer == 'yes' and answer != compHigh:
        print('Congratulations %s, you are %s! I am not.' % (var1, var2))
        break
    if answer == 'yes' and answer == compHigh:
        print('Ayyyyeee, %s! We are both %s!' % (var1, var2))
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: That's because `compHigh` can never be equal to `'yes'`. It is either `'no'` or `False`.

Comment: Review again how the expression `x if y else z` works.